# VB2013でForm1クラスからForm2クラスの関数(Sub)を呼び出すことができました． しかし

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

VB2013で`Form1`クラスから`Form2`クラスの関数(Sub)を呼び出すことができました．
しかし，その関数中で記述した`Form2`への描画が発生しません．

流れ（①～②）をまとめると
①`Form1`内：

```
Dim f2 as New Form2
f2.描画を記述した関数()
```

②`Form2`, 描画を記述した関数（）内：

```
Dim image As New Bitmap(picturebox1.Width,.....
Dim image_g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)

image_g.DrawLineやらFillEllipseやら...
```

なぜか，②の内部の描画だけが動きません．
`Form2`の`timer.tick`では普通に描画されるのですが，関数呼び出しの際のみ描画されません。

どうしてでしょうか？
早急な返答お待ちしています
明示的にアクティブにしても描画せず....`Conosole.WriteLine`は表示されるのです．

どうしても画面を2つ（`Form1`,`Form2`)表示させ，片方は（数値）確認用，もう一方は描画用と振り分けようとしたのですが...

補足と修正 `Form1`→`Form2`→`Button`でプログラムを手動で開始動作が開始され，
 →`Module 自作Timer`から数値データを取得→`Module 数値計算`へ 
→`Module 数値計算`内にあるSub関数より計算動作を行う 
→その後，`Sub 描画関数`にたどり着き，ここから`Form2`の描画関数を呼び込む
 でした.....
つまりは，`Module`から`Form2`の描画関数を呼び出しているのですが，
ファイルは出力されるものの`PictureBox`などには表示されないという‌​問題でした....

更に，`Form2`の`Load`の時点で`f2.Form2.ActivateForm()`とした上で Sub　描画関数にたどり着き，`Form2`の描画関数を呼び込む流れにしますと，一瞬だけ描画が行われました（不完全） その後，`Form2`内にある描画関数の中にある`PictureBox`などがグレーにハイライトされ，動作が止まってしまいます

Comment: フォームはそれぞれ別スレッドで動いているので、リフレッシュの通知をしないと画面には反映されないのだと思います。.NETは長いこと触っていないので回答として書けませんが`f2.Refresh()`とするか、コントロールそれぞれを`.Update()`するか、それよりも、更新したい変数をプロパティーとして外部からいじれるようにして、その変数はデータバインドを使ってUIが自動的に再描画がされるようにするのがよいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

> dim f2 as new form2
>   f2.描画を記述した関数()

とのことですが、 f2 はいつ表示するつもりでしょうか？ 別の箇所で new form2 を実行しそれを表示している場合は、インスタンスが異なるためf2に対する描画内容は別インスタンスへは反映されません。

Comment: ①Form1で数値計算を行い，その後その結果をForm2で描画します．
この間の流れとしてはForm1を起動，Form1のボタンより，Form2を起動しておいてから，①の流れ（この流れはプログラムが終了するまで繰り返します）である数値計算を開始します．
そのため，f2を呼び出す際はForm2は既に起動しており，①の流れにおける描画でForm1では数値を可視化することはコチラの都合上できないため，Form2に描画しようとしてf2を呼び出そうとしているということなのです．
しかし，これはSayuriさんに指摘していただいたとおりインスタンスが異なると考えていいのでしょうか．この問題として，Form2(起動済み)とf2は同じものと思っていたのですが，実は別物と考えるべきということでしょうか

Comment: 追記です．
どうやら，Form2への描画はされているようです（ファイルで出力されている）
ただ，Form2自身に直接的な描画がされず，Form2がLoadしたときのままになっています．